# How to detect use of query parameters not referenced in the corresponding DTO?

Tags: validation, dto, nestjs

Is there any way to detect when a request contains a query parameter that is not referenced in its corresponding DTO?

For example, if I have the following query DTO:

```js
export class GetCustomersQueryDTO {
    readonly firstName: string;
    readonly lastName: string;
}
```

How do I know it when the request contains a query parameter other than `firstName` or  `lastName`? For example: `/customers?name=jon`

Answer (score 2):

In the way I understand your question, I would say that you can achieve this using the `ValidationPipe` from NestJS itself.

You might need to tweak it a bit to suit your needs properly though, depending on whether you just need to reject those requests with unknown DTO attributes (in this case, then you can use the `ValidationPipe` options), or if you need to do further processing (in which case you would maybe use `interceptor` feature from NestJS).

See this page which might help you: 
https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator

Based on the above documentation link & [Nest built-in ValidationPipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#the-built-in-validationpipe), your first comment to my answer, and the [class-validator options docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#passing-options), the use of the `ValidationPipe` for your use case would look something like this:

```js
@Post()
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ forbidUnknownValues: true }))
async search(@Body() getCustomersQueryDto: GetCustomersQueryDTO) {
  this.usersService.search(getCustomersQueryDto);
}
```

N.B. 1: This will throw an error when a request contains attributes that are not defined within the `CreateCatDto` class. See the validation options for more tweaking.

N.B. 2: You could use the above pipe at the controller level (in the above sample code it's at the route/method level only within the controller)

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't figure out how to use the `ValidationPipe` to reject requests with unknown DTO attributes... The documentation doesn't help :/

Comment: I updated my answer with the proper link to the built-in Nest `ValidationPipe`, which you can use easily with the proper validation options from `class-validator` package (used under the hood by the built-in Nest's `ValidationPipe`)

Comment: I know it's too late but, commenting this for somebody else who would land on this page looking for the solution.

This was mentioned in NestJS's official documentation.

"Alternatively, you can stop the request from processing when non-whitelisted properties are present, and return an error response to the user. To enable this, set the `forbidNonWhitelisted` option property to `true`, in combination with setting `whitelist` to `true`."